# How to parse XML log file in logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-4, logstash-grok

I am having a sample log file like below

```
<error message="file missing">
      <value>01</value>
 </error>
<dealer id="01" data="some text">Approved</dealer>
```

I want to parse the above code and want to display the data in Kibana like `@message="file missing", @value="01", @dealer_id="01", @dealer_data = "some text"`.

I am new to ELK framework . I have tried using xpath filters but no luck if anyone help me with sample code means it would be a great help.

Comment: Have you tried the XML filter?  http://www.logstash.net/docs/latest/filters/xml

Comment: yes. I have tried it. filter{ xml{source => "@message" store_XML= false xpath["/error/@message","message","/error/value",value]}}. I am getting output like @message = "<error message="file missing">
      <value>01</value>
 </error>
<dealer id="01" data="some text">Approved</dealer>". I want to split the output which I mentioned above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fetching data can be done with xpath like this :

```
    xml {
      source => "message"
      store_xml => false
      xpath => {
        "//site/text()" => "site"
        "//dateCreation[1]/text()" => "date_creation"
        "//commande:Tiers[1]/identifiant/text()" => "tiers_id"
      }
    }
```

Then every result of the xpath is stored in the targeted field
You might replace/delete then existing field of your event to keep only the needed data.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample is one message, it needs a container, e.g.:

```
<foo>
  <error message="file missing">
    <value>01</value>
  </error>
  <dealer id="01" data="some text">Approved</dealer>
<foo>
```

This xml{} filter will process that (note "message" instead of your "@message")

```
filter {
  xml {
   source => "message"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Then how can fetch the data from dealer id , data and value tag. Can you please post the code for parsing it.